# parsing excel documents with python

Tags: python, excel, parsing

I want to parse excel document to lists in Python.
Is there a python library which is helpful for this action?
And what functions are relevant in that library?

Comment: can you export the Excel file as csv?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I open an Excel file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239207/how-can-i-open-an-excel-file-in-python)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You're best bet for parsing Excel files would be the [xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) library.  The [python-excel.org](http://www.python-excel.org/) site has links and examples for [xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) and related python excel libraries, including a [pdf document](http://www.simplistix.co.uk/presentations/python-excel.pdf) that has some good examples of using xlrd. Of course, there are also lots of [related xlrd questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python%20xlrd) on StackOverflow that might be of use.

<strike>One caveat with the xlrd library is that it will only work with `xls` (Excel 2003 and earlier versions of excel) file formats and not the more recent `xlsx` file format. There is   a newer library [openpyxl](https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/wiki/Home) for dealing with the `xlsx`, but I have never used it.</strike>

**UPDATE**:
As per John's comment, the [xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) library now supports both `xls` and `xlsx` file formats.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @John Machin, the principal maintainer of xlrd, has been known to frequent SO.

Comment: Related question concerning xlsx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371163/reading-xlsx-files-using-python

Comment: `xlrd` now reads both .xlsx and .xls files.

Comment: xlrd no longer supports xlsx. The last version supporting xlsx is 1.0.2

Answer (score 28):

The [pandas library](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) has a quick and easy way to read excel.  If it's mostly just data and nothing too complicated it'll work:

```
import pandas as pd
ex_data = pd.read_excel('excel_file.xlsx')
```

It reads it into a [pandas DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html), which is handy for data munging, etc.

To go to a list:

```
ex_data['column1_name'].values.tolist()
```

If you have multiple tables and things in each worksheet then you may want to use another library such as xlrd or openpyxl.

Comment: pandas library depends on xlrd < 2.0 or openpyxl to read xslx files under the hood

Answer (score 15):

openpyxl is a great library and supports read/write to 2010 xlsx files.

**sample parsing code**

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
for row in ws.iter_rows():
   for cell in row:
     print cell.value
```

**sample writing code**

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

wb = Workbook()

dest_filename = 'empty_book.xlsx'

ws1 = wb.active
ws1.title = "range names"

for row in range(1, 40):
    ws1.append(range(600))
wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

you can read more here: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Comment: And is the recommended library on python-excel.org

Comment: thanks for the sample code, the docs are lacking.

Comment: I am a developer just researching parsing techniques. This is excellent

Answer (score 6):

xlrd is great for simple tasks, but if you need to work with any of Excel's deeper functionality (macros, advanced plotting, etc), and you are working on a windows machine, you can use the pywin32 library to control the win32com layer.  This provides access to just about everything that can be controlled via macros / Visual Basic.

Comment: the link is dead now

Answer (score 2):

If you want to parse `xlsx` try [python-xlsx](https://github.com/staale/python-xlsx)

Answer (score -1):

[pyExcelerator](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyExcelerator/) does not seem to be maintained any more, but I have been using it for quite some time and have come to really like it.

Key Points:

- Platform independent
- Does not require Excel to be installed (meaning does not us COM communications)

**Update**

All of my new projects have moved to xlrd.

Comment: This is worse in every way than the newer `xlrd`.

Comment: @JohnY I would have to agree with you at this point.  This still however worked at the time.