# Open an existing excel workbook using pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

So far I've seen examples of invoking an Excel Application using pywinauto. Can I open an existing Excel Workbook using pywinauto ?

Comment: Could you clarify, the problem is how to run Excell using pywinauto?

Comment: No. The question is how to open an existing Excel workbook using pywinauto.

Comment: If you need just to parse *.xls file try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372716/parsing-excel-documents-with-python

Comment: Also you may automate via COM http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467229/automation-excel-from-python

Comment: So, If I've understood you right, pywinauto cannot open existing excel workbooks. Correct?

Comment: Richie, I cannot help you since I do not get your point. pywinauto probably can automate a UI, does not matter what's open

Answer (score 0):

You Don't even need pywinauto for this.  Just open excel with subprocess and use [command line switches](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/command-line-switches-for-excel-HA010158030.aspx) to open your doc

But if you insist on using pywinauto

Then Try

```
.MenuSelect("File -> Open")
```

Then

```
.Edit.TypeKeys("*Filename with absolutepath*", with_spaces = True)
```

Then

```
.No.Click()
```

Or something to that effect if those are not the actual elements names