# Why does my openpyxl WorkBook.active() give me a TypeError: Object is not callable?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying out openpyxl for the first time. I have an excel file, with two columns of data. Column 'A' has ID-numbers, while column 'C' has values. I am simply trying to extract them, as a plain key/value object.

These are the pseudo steps I figure i need to implement

- Find the file by location, and create a workbook object
- Define a WorkSheet object. In my case, this is the default first page
- Iterate through the rows, as long as there are key values in column 'A'
- Add key and value from 'A' and 'C' into an object.

The problem is that I can't get past step 2, creating a worksheet. The line `ws = wb.active()`seems like a completely standardized way of getting the default WorkSheet. I see it used in a lot of examples, and as of writing this, there are 93 questions on SO using the line. But in my case, it throws an error:

```
  File "C:\myworkspace\Myclass.py", line 18, in <module>
    ws = wb.active()
TypeError: 'ReadOnlyWorksheet' object is not callable
```

I am quite new to Python, but I've run into similar errors before. I know that it is thrown for instance if I import a python module name, instead of the relevant class name. What exactly is happening here? Why is this seemingly standard method of retrieving a worksheet object, trying to instanciate a module instead of a class? Am I using it wrong?

```
file_url = 'C:/myfilepath.xlsx'
key_column_index = 1
value_column_index = 3
row_start = 2

request_map = {}

wb = load_workbook(filename = file_url, use_iterators = True)
ws = wb.active()

row_counter = row_start

while( ws.cell(row=row_counter, column=key_column_index).value ):
    key = ws.cell(row=row_counter, column=key_column_index).value
    value = ws.cell(row=row_counter, column=value_column_index).value
    request_map[key] = value

    row_counter += 1

pprint(dict([(n, tuple(l.split(';'))) for n, l in enumerate(requests.split('\n'))]))
```

**Just to make this really really weird, I present you with this:**

I wanted to reproduce my error in the simplest possible way, so I found the shortest example I could, and copied it into my workspace. With the exception of the file path, this is completely identical to Ryu_Hayabusa's answer to this question: [parsing excel documents with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372716/parsing-excel-documents-with-python/32535915#32535915). Now get this: It works, without any errors!

```
file_url = 'C:/myfilepath.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(file_url)
ws = wb.active
for row in ws.iter_rows():
   for cell in row:
     print cell.value
```

Of course, i suspected that the bold text in the line

wb = load_workbook(**filename =** file_url **, use_iterators = True** )

was the problem, but no. Removing the bold marked text, to make it identical to the working example, still produced an error. The only difference is that now it says `Worksheet` instead of `ReadOnlyWorksheet` What in the big wide world is going on here???

Comment: I would start by removing the `()` from `wb.active()`, it is not needed.

Comment: The traceback tells you: `wb.active` is not callable.  It is a normal attribute, not a method.

Comment: You should also get used to using load_workbork(…, read_only=True)

Comment: @CharlieClark, why is that?

Comment: Because "use_iterators" is deprecated and being dropped in openpyxl 2.4

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In openpyxl, [wb.active](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html?highlight=active#openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.active) is provided by the library as a property giving you the currently active worksheet. As such you do not need to add `()` to call it as a function.

```
ws = wb.active
```

Your cut down example does it correctly.

Comment: Oh my lord... Thank you. I've been doing the exact same thing before. It's been a few months since i did Python, and I forgot to check this. Thank you.

Comment: Well, technically it's a property. I have a particular dislike for methods with "get" in their name and try to find Pythonic equivalents. But it's sort of difficult to find a Python analogue for "active" so I went with a property.