# How to create an array from an Excel with several sheets in Python

Tags: python, excel

I have an Excel with 18 sheets, and each one has more or less 20 columns with exactly 100 data each one (2000 data approx).

I would like to create an array with 18 items (1 per sheet), and each item with the 2000 data one after the other, I mean, to join a column ending element followed by the first of the next column.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: do you mean list of dataframes? one per sheet?

Comment: No, a dataframe with 18 lists, one per sheet. Sorry for not explaining myself good, I'm new in this world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [parse-excel-github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372716/parsing-excel-documents-with-python):

---

```
import xlrd

    book = xlrd.open_workbook("myfile.xls")
    print("The number of worksheets is {0}".format(book.nsheets))
    print("Worksheet name(s): {0}".format(book.sheet_names()))
    sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    print("{0} {1} {2}".format(sh.name, sh.nrows, sh.ncols))
    print("Cell D30 is {0}".format(sh.cell_value(rowx=29, colx=3)))

    for rx in range(sh.nrows):
         print(sh.row(rx))z
```

---

&&

[related-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372716/parsing-excel-documents-with-python):

good luck!