# Open a file for writing

Tags: python, file

When i try to open a file, even if it is not opened until that moment, it gives an error about that and therefore i cant write on it. Here is my python code:

```
try:
    myfile = open("SolvedFromFile.xls", "r+")
except IOError:
    mesaj=u"Açık olan nokta listesini kapatın!"
    wx.MessageBox(mesaj, u"UYARI")
```

What can cause that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it gives you an error about what?

Comment: Remove the exception handling and try again.  Your exception handler is hiding our best hope of figuring out what's going on.  If you must handle exceptions, please at least use the traceback library (http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) to inspect the exception and give useful information.

Comment: Maybe the file doesn't exist?? The file must exist when opening in r+ mode...

Comment: `r+` mode open file for both reading and writing, so if file doesn't exist it will not create a new file instead will give error `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'SolvedFromFile.xls'`

Comment: To open excel(.xls) file in python http://stackoverflow.com/q/3239207/776084

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you should use a [with statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) here

Comment: @Shansal does your code have `'path\to\file.xls'` instead of `'path\\to\\file.xls'` ?

Comment: I second @wim's comment that you should be using the `with` statement. See the first example [here](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.g. you script has no rights to read...rarely happens on your own computer. most seen on productive environment.

or file not found(?)

Comment: file doesnt exist in the path

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the caught exception to see what the cause is:

```
try:
    myfile = open(...)
except IOError as (errno, strerror):
    print 'Error code %d: %s' % (errno, strerror)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the full address in the open() method. Also check if the file exists or not and your have rights to that location. All the best.