# Convert excel sheets with images to PDF files

Tags: python, automation

I'm trying to automate a process that converts excel files with single sheets having charts into pdf files using python. Any packages available that would help this task?

I have tried Excel Writer and other similar packages, it doesn't seem to work.
Reading the file using pandas doesn't work.
The source file has charts/images.

PDF file for each excel file is the desired output. Any suggestions would be welcome..

Comment: have you tried this : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683376/print-chosen-worksheets-in-excel-files-to-pdf-in-python

Comment: Thanks @asimo. I have written a similar powershell script for this requirement.