# What does "o.Visible = False" actually do in the post?

Tags: python, excel, pdf, pywin32, win32com

I am reading a link regarding excel to PDF:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31813137/12252446

The answer snippet:

```
import win32com.client

o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

o.Visible = False

wb_path = r'c:\user\desktop\sample.xls'

wb = o.Workbooks.Open(wb_path)



ws_index_list = [1,4,5] #say you want to print these sheets

path_to_pdf = r'C:\user\desktop\sample.pdf'



wb.WorkSheets(ws_index_list).Select()

wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, path_to_pdf)
```

I want to know what does "o.Visible = False" do here?

Thank you.

Comment: Makes the Excel Application hidden.

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean the excel file is hidden in the respective folder? Nothing will go wrong if I skip this line right?

Comment: No that makes the open instance of the application hidden. Nothing to do with files.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks a lot.