# Convert Excel into Pdf having AttributeError error

Tags: python

I use code from this thread [Print chosen worksheets in excel files to pdf in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683376/print-chosen-worksheets-in-excel-files-to-pdf-in-python) to convert Excel file to Pdf.

It was working fine and suddendly, it now give me error below at this line
`wb.WorkSheets(ws_index_list).Select()`

(The code opens Excel file fine)

**AttributeError**: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library._Workbook instance at 0x2758034291872>' object has no attribute 'WorkSheets'

---> 21 wb.WorkSheets(ws_index_list).Select()
22 wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, path_to_pdf)

```
import win32com.client
o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
# o = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
o.Visible = False

# Path to Excel file
wb_path = r'~\Sample Invoice1.xlsx'

wb = o.Workbooks.Open(wb_path)
print('type of wb:',type(wb))
 
    
ws_index_list = [1] #say you want to print these sheets

path_to_pdf = r'~/Sample Invoice1.pdf'
wb.WorkSheets(ws_index_list).Select()
wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, path_to_pdf)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the attribute is called `Sheets` and not `WorkSheets`.

So you'll change your second-to-last-line to:

```py
wb.Sheets(ws_index_list.Select()
```

Comment: Also, you'll want to make sure you quit everything when you are done. That is, you probably want to add `wb.Close()` and `o.Quit()` to the end of it all.