# Parsing XML with namespaces into a dataframe

Tags: python, xml, pandas, elementtree

I have the following simpplified XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"> 
    <soap:Body>
        <ReadResponse xmlns="ABCDEFG.com">
            <ReadResult>
                <Value>
                    <Alias>x1</Alias>
                    <Timestamp>2013-11-11T00:00:00</Timestamp>
                    <Val>113</Val>
                    <Duration>5000</Duration>
                    <Quality>128</Quality>
                </Value>
                <Value>
                    <Alias>x1</Alias>
                    <Timestamp>2014-11-11T00:02:00</Timestamp>
                    <Val>110</Val>
                    <Duration>5000</Duration>
                    <Quality>128</Quality>
                </Value>
                <Value>
                    <Alias>x2</Alias>
                    <Timestamp>2013-11-11T00:00:00</Timestamp>
                    <Val>101</Val>
                    <Duration>5000</Duration>
                    <Quality>128</Quality>
                </Value>
                <Value>
                    <Alias>x2</Alias>
                    <Timestamp>2014-11-11T00:02:00</Timestamp>
                    <Val>122</Val>
                    <Duration>5000</Duration>
                    <Quality>128</Quality>
                </Value>
            </ReadResult>
        </ReadResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and would like to parse it into a dataframe with the following structure (keeping some of the tags and discarding the rest):

```
Timestamp                x1    x2
2013-11-11T00:00:00      113  101
2014-11-11T00:02:00      110  122
```

The problem is since the XML file includes namespaces, I don't know how to proceed. I have gone through several tutorials (e.g., https://docs.python.org/2/library/pyexpat.html) and questions (e.g., How to open [this XML file to create dataframe in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077231/how-to-open-this-xml-file-to-create-dataframe-in-python) and [Parsing XML with namespace in Python via 'ElementTree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree)) but none of them have helped/worked. I appreciate if anyone can help me sorting this out.

Comment: You can find the answer here in the 3rd comment:
[How to set the `xpath` of pandas's read_xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68281666/how-to-set-the-xpath-of-pandass-read-xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example on how to parse an xml using lxml and xpaths:

```
from lxml import etree
namespaces = {'abc': "ABCDEFG.com"}
xmltree = etree.fromstring(xml_string)
items = xmltree.xpath('//abc:Alias/text()', namespaces=namespaces)

print items
```