# How to set the `xpath` of pandas's read_xml?

Tags: python, pandas, xml

I want to parse data from a [xml file](https://www.huaan.com.cn/etf/159949/etffiledownload.jsp?etffilename=pcf_159949_20210707.xml) of its `Component` part:

```
<Component>
  <UnderlyingSecurityID>300001</UnderlyingSecurityID>
  <UnderlyingSecurityIDSource>102</UnderlyingSecurityIDSource>
  <UnderlyingSymbol>特锐德</UnderlyingSymbol>
  <ComponentShare>300.00</ComponentShare>
  <SubstituteFlag>1</SubstituteFlag>
  <PremiumRatio>0.25000</PremiumRatio>
  <CreationCashSubstitute>0.0000</CreationCashSubstitute>
  <RedemptionCashSubstitute>0.0000</RedemptionCashSubstitute>
</Component>
<Component>
  <UnderlyingSecurityID>300003</UnderlyingSecurityID>
  <UnderlyingSecurityIDSource>102</UnderlyingSecurityIDSource>
  <UnderlyingSymbol>乐普医疗</UnderlyingSymbol>
  <ComponentShare>600.00</ComponentShare>
  <SubstituteFlag>1</SubstituteFlag>
  <PremiumRatio>0.25000</PremiumRatio>
  <CreationCashSubstitute>0.0000</CreationCashSubstitute>
  <RedemptionCashSubstitute>0.0000</RedemptionCashSubstitute>
</Component>
```

I have installed the latest version of lxml and pandas, tried following codes without luck.

```
Python 3.9.4 (tags/v3.9.4:1f2e308, Apr  6 2021, 13:40:21) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.25.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: pd.__version__
Out[2]: '1.3.0'

In [3]: xml = pd.read_xml('https://www.huaan.com.cn/etf/159949/etffiledownload.jsp?etffilename=pcf_159949_20210707.xml', xpath='//component')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-67d228028cc9> in <module>
----> 1 xml = pd.read_xml('https://www.huaan.com.cn/etf/159949/etffiledownload.jsp?etffilename=pcf_159949_20210707.xml', xpath='//component')

...
    501         if elems == []:
--> 502             raise ValueError(msg)
    503 
    504         if elems != [] and attrs == [] and children == []:

ValueError: xpath does not return any nodes. Be sure row level nodes are in xpath. If document uses namespaces denoted with xmlns, be sure to define namespaces and use them in xpath.

In [4]: xml = pd.read_xml('https://www.huaan.com.cn/etf/159949/etffiledownload.jsp?etffilename=pcf_159949_20210707.xml', xpath='//component', namespaces={'com': 'http://ts.szse.cn/Fund'})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-52fbe542dadb> in <module>
----> 1 xml = pd.read_xml('https://www.huaan.com.cn/etf/159949/etffiledownload.jsp?etffilename=pcf_159949_20210707.xml', xpath='//component', namespaces={'com': 'http://ts.szse.cn/Fund'})

...
    501         if elems == []:
--> 502             raise ValueError(msg)
    503 
    504         if elems != [] and attrs == [] and children == []:

ValueError: xpath does not return any nodes. Be sure row level nodes are in xpath. If document uses namespaces denoted with xmlns, be sure to define namespaces and use them in xpath.
```

I also tried `lxml` directly, which seems work:

```
In [5]: from lxml import etree
In [6]: import requests
In [7]: content = requests.get('https://www.huaan.com.cn/etf/159949/etffiledownload.jsp?etffilename=pcf_159949_20210707.xml').content

In [8]: html = etree.HTML(content)
In [9]: html.xpath('//component')
Out[9]: 
[<Element component at 0x1d493cb23c0>,
 <Element component at 0x1d493cb2340>,
 <Element component at 0x1d493cb2240>,
 <Element component at 0x1d493cb22c0>,
 <Element component at 0x1d493cb2140>,
 <Element component at 0x1d493cb2040>,
 <Element component at 0x1d493cb2c40>,
 <Element component at 0x1d493cb61c0>,
 <Element component at 0x1d493cb63c0>,
 <Element component at 0x1d493cb2200>,
 ...
```

I have no idea why the `read_xml` does not work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure, but I think youo forgot the dot in the xpath --> `'.//Component'`

Comment: It does not work .@coco18

Comment: Try it, with the namespace included : ``pd.read_xml(file_path, xpath=".//doc:Component", namespaces={"doc":"http://ts.szse.cn/Fund"})``

Comment: @sammywemmy Thanks, this works. I find out that the prefix dot does not matter, but xpath is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in short the solution here is to figure out which node you want, in this case the `Component` (case-sensitive), and set the xpath as follows adding `//`.

```
pd.read_xml(your_xml_file, xpath='//Component')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use xml.etree.ElementTree, instead of `pd.xml_read()`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://www.huaan.com.cn/etf/159949/etffiledownload.jsp?etffilename=pcf_159949_20210707.xml'
response = requests.get(url)
res = ET.fromstring(response.content)

tree = ET.ElementTree(res)
root = tree.getroot()

namespace = "{http://ts.szse.cn/Fund}"

columns =['UnderlyingSecurityID', 'UnderlyingSecurityIDSource', 'UnderlyingSymbol', 'ComponentShare', 'SubstituteFlag', 'PremiumRatio','CreationCashSubstitute', 'RedemptionCashSubstitute']

data = []
for elem in root: 
    if elem.tag == f"{namespace}Components":
        com_l = []
        for com in elem.findall(f"{namespace}Component"):
            for val in com:
                com_l.append(val.text)
            data.append(com_l)
            com_l =[]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
print(df.to_string())
```