# read xls file in pandas / python: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\xef\xbb\xbf<?xml'

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to open an `xls` file (with only one tab) into a pandas dataframe.

It is a file that i can normally read in excel or excel for the web, in fact here is the raw file itself: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/zbxg8ymjp8zxo6k4an4dj/product-screener.xls?dl=0&rlkey=3aw7whab78jeexbdkthkjzkmu .

I notice that the top two rows have merged cells and so do some of the columns.

I have tried several methods (from stack), which all fail.

```
# method 1 - read excel
file = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\product-screener.xls"
df = pd.read_excel(file)
print(df)
```

error: `Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.`

```
# method 2 - pip install xlrd and use engine
file = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\product-screener.xls"
df = pd.read_excel(file, engine='xlrd')
print(df)
```

error: `Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\xef\xbb\xbf<?xml'`

```
# method 3 - rename to xlsx and open with openpyxl
file = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\product-screener.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(file, engine='openpyxl')
print(df)
```

error: `File is not a zip file`
(possibly converting, as opposed to renaming, is an option).

```
# method 4 - use read_xml
file = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\product-screener.xls"
df = pd.read_xml(file)
print(df)
```

this method actually yields a result, but produces a DataFrame that has no meaning in relation to the sheet. presumably one needs to interpret the xml (seems complex) ?

```
   Style       Name  Table
0    NaN       None    NaN
1    NaN  All funds    NaN


# method 5 - use read_table
file = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\product-screener.xls"
df = pd.read_table(file)
print(df)
```

This method reads the file into a one column (series) DataFrame. So how could one use this info to create a standard 2d DataFrame in the same shape as the xls file ?

```
0       <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:off...
1                                                <Styles>
2                                 <Style ss:ID="Default">
3                          <Alignment Horizontal="Left"/>
4                                                </Style>
...                                                   ...
226532                                            </Cell>
226533                                             </Row>
226534                                           </Table>
226535                                       </Worksheet>
226536                                        </Workbook>



# method 5 - use read_html
file = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\product-screener.xls"
df = pd.read_html(file)
print(df)
```

this returns a blank list `[]` whereas one might have expected at least a list of DataFrames.

So the question is what is the easiest method to read this file into a dataframe (or similar usable format) ?

Comment: link to file (on google docs) here too: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YPaFg-cLJCpJb5EhEGtV9TcDSgQaKxVo/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106649036151775603005&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: You `"xls"` file is actually an `xml Spreadsheet` file (just view it with e.g. notepad). Pandas/openpyxl can't read this kind of spreadsheet file. You can try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33504236/3944322) as a workaround (I didn't test it though).

Comment: this appears to be a closer solution (hence the upvote), but not complete yet. A small portion (from rows 800 to 870), **but not all** of the data is now parsed into the DataFrame. The headers are missing too. So the question is how to capture all the data with the method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete solution but it should get you started. The `"xls"` file is actually a plain `xml` file in the `SpreadsheetML` format. Change the file extension to `.xml` an view it in your internet browser, the structure (at least of the give file) is rather straightforward.

The following reads the data contents into a pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('product-screener.xls')
root = tree.getroot()

data = [[c[0].text for c in r] for r in root[1][0][2:]]
types = [c[0].get('{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Type') for c in root[1][0][2]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.replace('-', None)
for c in df.columns:
    if types[c] == 'Number':
        df[c] = pd.to_numeric(df[c])
    elif types[c] == 'DateTime':
        df[c] = pd.to_datetime(df[c])
```

Getting the column names from rows 0 and 1 is a bit more involved due to the merged cells - I leave it as an exercise for the reader .

Comment: This method works (aside form the headers). Presumably one needs to include the rename (or a copy) of `xls` file to `xml` file and then delete the `xml` once finished with. I will try to include this in a more complete method. I have voted this up as it is, so far, the best answer.

Comment: I added `shutil.copyfile(file_xls, file_xml)` to transform xls to xml. This completes the process aside from the headers. A final edit of the header rows (1 & 2) would complete.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the full solution here which contains the above approved solution (by @Stef) plus the final addition of the headers into the DataFrame.

```
'''
get xls file
convert to xml
parse into dataframe
add headers

'''


import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

import shutil

file_xls = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\product-screener.xls"
file_xml = 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\product-screener.xml'

shutil.copyfile(file_xls, file_xml)

tree = ET.parse(file_xml)
root = tree.getroot()

data = [[c[0].text for c in r] for r in root[1][0][2:]]
types = [c[0].get('{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Type') for c in root[1][0][2]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.replace('-', None)
for c in df.columns:
    if types[c] == 'Number':
        df[c] = pd.to_numeric(df[c])
    elif types[c] == 'DateTime':
        df[c] = pd.to_datetime(df[c])

print(df)


headers = [[c[0].text for c in r] for r in root[1][0][:2]]
# print(headers[0])
# print(len(headers[0]))
# print()
# print(headers[1])
# print(len(headers[1]))
# print()

# upto column (AF) comes from headers[0]
df_headers = headers[0][0:32]
# the next 9 are discrete
x_list = ['discrete: ' + s for s in headers[1][0:9]  ]
df_headers = df_headers + x_list

# the next 10 are annualised
x_list = ['annualised: ' + s for s in headers[1][9:19]  ]
df_headers = df_headers + x_list

# the next 10 are cumulative
x_list = ['cumulative: ' + s for s in headers[1][19:29]  ]
df_headers = df_headers + x_list

# the next 9 are calendar
x_list = ['calendar: ' + s for s in headers[1][29:38]  ]
df_headers = df_headers + x_list

# the next 5 are portfolio characteristics (metrics)
x_list = ['metrics: ' + s for s in headers[1][38:43]  ]
df_headers = df_headers + x_list

# the next 6 are portfolio characteristics
x_list = ['characteristics: ' + s for s in headers[1][43:49]  ]
df_headers = df_headers + x_list

# the final 5 are sustainability characteristics
x_list = ['sustain: ' + s for s in headers[1][49:54]  ]
df_headers = df_headers + x_list
print(df_headers)

# add headers to dataframe
df.columns = df_headers
print(df)
```