# Having difficulties to open an old format xls file with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl, xlrd

I have a spreadsheet which is in format of Microsoft Excel 97-2003 xls. I tried following:

```
import pandas as pd

xlsx_file_path = "C:/temp/a_file.xls"
sheets_dict = pd.read_excel(xlsx_file_path, engine='xlrd', sheet_name=None)

for sheet_name, df_in in sheets_dict.items():
    print(sheet_name)
```

It gives error:

```
  File C:\xxxxxx\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py:172 in open_workbook
    bk = open_workbook_xls(

  File C:\xxxxxxx\site-packages\xlrd\book.py:79 in open_workbook_xls
    biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)

  File C:\xxxxxxxx\site-packages\xlrd\book.py:1284 in getbof
    bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])

  File C:\xxxxxxxx\site-packages\xlrd\book.py:1278 in bof_error
    raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)

XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\xef\xbb\xbf\xef\xbb\xbf<?'
```

I tried other engines such as openpyxl, and got following error:

```
  File C:\xxxx\lib\zipfile.py:1336 in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Is there any workaround?

The actual file is:
https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239566/ishares-iboxx-investment-grade-corporate-bond-etf/1521942788811.ajax?fileType=xls&fileName=iShares-iBoxx--Investment-Grade-Corporate-Bond-ETF_fund&dataType=fund

Comment: Microsoft does an OK job of supporting back compat. Use some version of Excel to open the ancient document, and write it back out in CSV or other useful format.

Comment: I need to do it programmatically as this file may get updated by its publisher.

Comment: Is that an excel file or an exported CSV file? XLRD is looking for the Excel BOF (Beginning of File) but it seems like you get two text BOM (Byte Order Mark) claiming utf-8 encoding. Nothing definitive, but try opening with a text editor that understands byte-order-marks (wordpad perhaps?) and see what it looks like. Alternately, open with python in bindary mode and read the first, say, 64 bytes.

Comment: If you can get excel to read the file, then you could write a VB script that creates CSV files. Run that from your python program as a preprocessor.

Comment: Use `file` in WSL2 Linux command line to get some  info about the type of the file.

Comment: *XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\xef\xbb\xbf\xef\xbb\xbf<?'* This is the error you would get trying to read a CSV file using 'read_excel', use 'read_csv'.

Comment: It is an Excel file since it has multiple sheets.

Comment: The magic number is for a text file (CSV is a text file). However, looking at the attached file, it is in an XML format, I think Office 2003 SpreadsheetML. Still `read_xml` seems to have issues reading this format. You can try searching about & playing around with load options and see if you can get it to load. However given that Excel can open the file apparently intact it's probably easier to just load into Excel and save as XLSX file and have done with it. If there are multiple files you can use Xlwings or win32com to open and save in another format

Comment: Microsoft has in the past used several completely different file formats with the XLS extension and what you're seeing is why this is not a good idea. You'll either need to see if someone has developed a parser for this file format, or write your own. In any case, see if you can find some documentation for it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The XLS file is a birany file that is not in the Zipped file format.
Because that you have an ZIP error when you're using the openpyxl engine. You can leave the engine empty and the pandas select to you.

Now checking the Microsoft Excel 97-2003 XML spreadsheet problem, I've developed an reader based on this documentation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from io import StringIO ## for Python 3
import re

### Performs some cleanup at the generate XML
### These cleanups are based on https://www.ishares.com/ needs
### You need to customized based on your personal needs
def cleanup(xml):
    # Remooving multiple BOM at the file
    xml = xml.replace('\ufeff', '')
    # Regular expression that finds "&" with no ";" at next 5 positions
    pattern = r'&(?!(?:.*?;){1,5})'
    
    # Replacing the alone "&""
    xml = re.sub(pattern, '&amp;', xml)
    
    # TODO you can perform others celeanup
    return xml

### Removing the namespace to improove the code readbility
def remove_namespace(tree):
    for elem in tree.iter():
        if '}' in elem.tag:
            elem.tag = elem.tag.split('}', 1)[1]
        for key in list(elem.attrib.keys()):
            if '}' in key:
                new_key = key.split('}', 1)[1]
                elem.attrib[new_key] = elem.attrib.pop(key)

### Extract data frame from xml and workSheet name/firstLine
def extract_data_from_xml(xml_file, sheets):
    df = {}
    prefix= u'{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}'
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    remove_namespace(tree)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for sheet_name, start_row in sheets.items():
        data = extract_data_from_root(root, sheet_name, start_row)
        if(len(data)>0):
            headers = data[0]
            df[sheet_name] = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=headers)
    return df

### Extracting data array from parsed xml root not from text, to improove performance
def extract_data_from_root(root, sheet_name, start_row):
    data = []
    found_table = False
    acc = 0
    for elem in root.iter():
        if found_table and elem.tag == 'Row':
            row_data = [cell.text for cell in elem.findall('Cell/Data')]
            if(acc>= start_row):
                data.append(row_data)
            else:
                acc +=1
        elif elem.tag == 'Table' or elem.tag == 'Worksheet':
            if elem.attrib.get('Name') == sheet_name:
                found_table = True
            else:
                if found_table and len(data)>0:
                    break
                else:
                    continue
    return data

### The core function
def read_XML_MS_spreadsheet(filename, sheets):
    with open(filename, mode="r", encoding="utf-8-sig") as fin:
        xml = fin.read()
        xml = cleanup(xml)
    df = extract_data_from_xml(StringIO(xml), sheets)
    return df

def read_XLS_and_XLSX_spreadsheet(filename, sheet_start_rows):
    dfs = {}
    for sheet_name, start_row in sheet_start_rows.items():
        df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet_name, header=start_row)
        dfs[sheet_name] = df
    return dfs

### main
sheets = {
    'Holdings' : 7,
    'Historical' : 0,
    'Performance' : 4,
    'Distributions' : 0
}
# Originaly posted on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77958287/having-difficulties-to-open-an-old-format-xls-file-with-python-pandas/77958383#77958383
# https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239566/ishares-iboxx-investment-grade-corporate-bond-etf/1521942788811.ajax?fileType=xls&fileName=iShares-iBoxx--Investment-Grade-Corporate-Bond-ETF_fund&dataType=fund
file_path = 'iShares-iBoxx--Investment-Grade-Corporate-Bond-ETF_fund.xls'

## Firstly try to read in XLSX or XLS. Pandas will choose the right one
try:
    df = read_XLS_and_XLSX_spreadsheet(file_path, sheets)
except Exception:
    try: ## If this isn't an XLS or XLSX file, try to load as an MS-XML 2003 Spreadsheet @see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats
        df = read_XML_MS_spreadsheet(file_path, sheets)
    except Exception: ## If still having an error, try to open an CSV file
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path) # CSV it's not multi-sheet

# Let's do some stufs
print(df)
```

**@edited 1**
Based on the error, you're problaby have an CSV file named as as XLS file.
try to change the read method to

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

**@edited 2**
After receiving the link to the specific file, I have enhanced the response by developing an MS-XML 2003 Spreadsheet reader. Additionally, I have conducted some cleanup on the externally generated XML file. As a result, the code is now compatible with various file formats such as XLSX, XLS, MS-XML, or CSV. You may input the spreadsheets along with the desired initial line for importing into the pandas DataFrame.

Comment: The `engine='xlrd'` option OP gives to `read_excel()` should have handled the old format, so this probably won't help. It's more likely the file is corrupted or not the expected type.

Comment: @joanis, you're right.

Comment: I've improved the answer based on the errors. Probably the file is ans CSV file named as an XLS file.

Comment: This does not answer the actual question.

Comment: @CharlieClark, based on the problem and the errors, the code solve the problem that is an CSV file named as an XLS file, and provide an workaround for this user misconfiguration. And the answer explain about both errors received by both engines. Plz reconsider your down vote.

Comment: It is a spreadsheet since it contains multiple sheets.

Comment: I've opened the provided file as text-File and It's an XML-MS Excel file. 
```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ss:Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
<ss:Styles>
...
```
I can't check this answer, but it's seems old but gold. You can try the best answer provided at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33470130/read-excel-xml-xls-file-with-pandas

Comment: So, still a guess and not an answer.

Comment: @CharlieClark, now we have the answer