# Change data in large excel file(more than 240 000 rows on sheet)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to change data in large excel file(more than 240 000 rows on sheet), it's possible through win32com.client, but I need use Linux OS ...

Please, could you advise something suitable!

Comment: If it's only once, I'd export the excel to csv, I'd edit it with python, and then I'd import into excel again.

Comment: why can't Excel do it?

Comment: Have you tried `openpyxl` or `pandas` (which uses `openpyxl` internally)?

Comment: You have not even mentioned the format. Is it XLS or XLSX?

Answer (score -1):

If it's raw data, I always export it to a .csv file and work on it directly. CSV is a simple format with one row per line and all the elements on the row separated with commas. Depending on what you want to do, it's not hard to write a python script to edit that.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question, rather a "do it this way instead"...

Comment: @EricThomas - `xlrd` only works on old Excel files; `openpyxl` is the recommended library to edit Excel files (see http://www.python-excel.org/)

Comment: What if the user needs to parse 1000 Excel files... why manually export when you have Excel file readers in Python? The output format might also need to be Excel files - manual export, process, manual import is a tedious workflow.

Comment: Very Thanks!
XLRD it's cool! The speed very fast! But i need to edit data in file, XLRD allowed me only read data, so i can use XLWD of  course, but my excel files has some sheets containing lage data, and if i  use XLRD/XLWD i will lose data from other sheets of my document.

Comment: Use Xlwings to edit data in large files

Answer (score -2):

`openpyxl` is the recommended python module to use (see http://www.python-excel.org/ )

You can use `openpyxl` directly or `pandas` (see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html) which wraps `openpyxl` offering a high level interface to the worksheet.

E.g.

```
df = pandas.read_excel(FILENAME)
# Manipulate data 
#...
df.to_excel(FILENAME)
```

**See also**

- [How can I open an Excel file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239207/how-can-i-open-an-excel-file-in-python)
- https://realpython.com/blog/python/working-with-large-excel-files-in-pandas/

Comment: Very Thanks!
but my test showed me that it requires more than 6 Gb memory and more than 45 minutes ((

Comment: How big is the original file?