# Reading Excel file: error matching date variable to Excel content

Tags: python, excel, datetime

I'm trying to make my program do a specific task when the content of the first row in my Excel file (which contains dates such as 2016-01-20) matches tomorrow's date, assigned to variable "d".

Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
reader = openpyxl.load_workbook(sys.argv[1])
sheet = reader.active

for row in range(4, sheet.max_row + 1):
    i = date.today()
    print i
    d = date.today() + timedelta(days=1)

    if row[0] == d:
        sms_count = 0
        total_sms_count = 0
        #do some task
```

However, I'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SMS_Sender.py", line 49, in <module>
    if row[0] == d:
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
Geralds-MacBook-Pro:demos geraldkwok$
```

Can anyone tell me why I can't match the dates in my Excel file column to the variable "d" - and what I can do to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: apparently your excel file has several columns and you are trying to check if the whole row matches your date, address only the affected column in your row

Comment: It is telling that you're trying to get an zero-th element of an int (`row[0]`). Is your variable `row` a list of integers, or something else?

Comment: @minitoto row[0] reads the first column of each row; the first column contains dates.

Comment: @nander my variable row is just each row in the excel file, which contains columns including dates and alphabet letters.

Comment: According to your error. `row` is a single number, a `int`

Comment: No, your `row` is an integer, namely an integer from `[4,5,6,...,sheet.max_row]`.

Comment: the error means that you're attempting to apply the index operator [] on an int, not a list. so row is not a list

Comment: What in my code is making my `row` an integer, and not a list? How do I change `row` into a list?

Comment: The for loop makes it so. On each iteration the `row` variable will be a integer from the list `range(4, sheet.max_row + 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, sorry for the fact that all our comments are somewhat confusing. What we mean is the following:

```
for row in range(4, sheet.max_row + 1):
    # do something
```

says: for each integer in the range 4 until sheet.max_row+1, do something.
You have to open the Excel file ([using xlrd or pandas is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239207/how-can-i-open-an-excel-file-in-python)) and read its lines into some list `rows`, for example. Then, you could do:

```
for row in rows:
```

and you will have a `row` that contains a sentence!

=====================================================================
EDIT:

Example code:

```
# Open the sheet
reader = openpyxl.load_workbook(sys.argv[1])
sheet = reader.active

# Get the day of tomorrow
d = date.today() + timedelta(days=1)

# For each row, compare first cell and day of tomorrow
for rowNum in range(1, sheet.max_row+1):
    firstCell = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=1)
    if int(firstCell) == d:
        # Do some task
```

I didn't test it, but this should do it, I think.

Comment: Edited my original post to show my variables `reader` and `sheet`; should I replace `for row in range...` with `for row in rows`, or should I add something like `for row in reader/sheet` under `for row in range..`?